# Embedded calendar stopped working

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I am responsible for maintaining 2 websites.  One is a Wordpress website that is just a list of events using Time.ly's All in One Event Calendar plugin.  The other is a conventional built from scratch website using html.

The html website has had code that embedded the Wordpress calendar feed into it for several years, and it's always worked fine and I haven't had to do anything with it.  Recently, it just stopped working.  The calendar feed is just gone with no errors returned, no problems loading the site or anything.  It looks as if somebody just deleted the code for it.  However, the code is still there and is as follows:

```
<script class="ai1ec-widget-placeholder" data-widget="ai1ec_superwidget" data-action="stream" data-tag_ids="45">
          (function(){var d=document,s=d.createElement('script'),
          i='ai1ec-script';if(d.getElementById(i))return;s.async=1;
          s.id=i;s.src='http://www.texascitycommunitycalendar.com/?ai1ec_js_widget';
          d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);})();
        </script>
```

Can anybody identify any obvious reason that that might have just stopped working?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason for that very last `()` pair in the `script` tag (just before the semicolon that is followed by the closing `</script>`tag. Try to erase it.